# ActionController Actions just need some clarification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing a book on Ruby/ROR and I'm using something called application controller. Would anyone be able to clarify on what an action is? Just wondering thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Rails documentation about routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more information about routes, controllers and actions.

For example, when this route is defined

```
get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show'
```

and you visit the URL

```
GET /patients/17
```

Then you are calling the action `show` in the `PatientsController`.